# Python List Multiplication on Function Call

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I'm using Python 2.7 and I ran into the following situation:

I have a Polygon object that consists of N vertices stored in a list. I have abstracted out a function `rand_xy()` that generates a random point to be a vertex, and I would like to create `Polygon` objects with N random vertices.

I tried this:

```
vertices = [ rand_xy() ] * N
```

but it makes a list of N vertices that are all the same. And I guess it makes sense because the call to rand_xy() is evaluated first, and then it is duplicated N times.

I wish it would instead make the list by calling `rand_xy()` N times. Is there any way to accomplish this (preferably in one line)?

I realized that the "obvious" way is to just do this:

```
vertices = []
for i in range( 0 , N ):
    vertices.append( rand_xy() )
```

but my `Polygon` constructor is

```
def __init__( self , vertices , color )
```

and I'd really like it if I could just set the default value of `vertices` to be a random list of N points like this:

```
def __init__( self , vertices = [ rand_xy() ] * N , color = rand_rgb() )
```

This way, calling the `Polygon` constructor with no arguments will give me a random new `Polygon`. Or is there a better design choice for the constructor? Or can this just not be done in Python?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, as you observed, when you do - `[ rand_xy() ] * N` - first the function call is evaluated and then the result in put in the list and then multiplied to create a list of `N` elements (though all same items).

You can do list comprehension instead of `[ rand_xy() ] * N` -

```
vertices = [rand_xy() for _ in range(N)]
```

This can be done in a single line.

---

But please note, you should not use this or any list as a default argument. I am guessing when you say you need to do -

```
def __init__( self , vertices = [ rand_xy() ] * N , color = rand_rgb() )
```

This means you are trying to use it as default argument. But please note, default arguments are only evaluated once, when the function is defined , it is not evaluated everytime the function is called without arguments. Check the question - ["Least Astonishment" and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument) - for more details.

Instead of that, you can use `None` or so and then create the default values inside the function body, if the values are None. Example -

```
def __init__( self , vertices = None , color = rand_rgb() )
    if vertices is None:
        vertices = [rand_xy() for _ in range(N)]
```

You can do same for `color` , if you want it to return a different random rgb value everytime you clal the function without arguments.

Answer (score 1):

to initialize your vertices to a default random value, you could do like this:

```
def __init__( self , vertices = None , color = rand_rgb() ):
    self.vertices = [rand_xy() for _ in range(N)] if vertices is None else vertices
```

It is not a good idea to assign default values to lists or other mutable structures.